# Keras Callback - Save the per-epoch outputs

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, callback

I am trying to create a callback for extracting the per-epoch outputs in the 1st hidden layer of my model. With what I have written, `self.model.layers[0].output` outputs a Tensor object but I could not see the actual entries.

Ideally I would like to save these output tensors, and visualise using an epoch vs mean-output plot. This has been implemented in Glorot & Bengio (2010) but the source code is not available.
[image]

How shall I edit my code in order to make the model fitting process save the outputs in each epoch? Thanks in advance.

```
class PerEpochOutputCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        print('First layer output of epoch:', epoch+1, self.model.layers[0].output)
    
model_relu_3= Sequential()  
# Use ReLU hidden layer
model_relu_3.add(Dense(3, input_dim= 8, activation= 'relu', kernel_initializer= 'uniform'))
model_relu_3.add(Dense(5, input_dim= 3, activation= 'relu', kernel_initializer= 'uniform'))
model_relu_3.add(Dense(5, input_dim= 5, activation= 'relu', kernel_initializer= 'uniform'))
model_relu_3.add(Dense(1, activation= 'sigmoid', kernel_initializer= 'uniform'))
model_relu_3.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics= ['accuracy'])


# Train model
tr_results = model_relu_3.fit(X, y, validation_split=0.2, epochs=10, batch_size=32, 
                             verbose=2, callbacks=[PerEpochOutputCallback()])

====
Train on 614 samples, validate on 154 samples
Epoch 1/10
First layer output of epoch: 1 Tensor("dense_42/Relu:0", shape=(None, 3), dtype=float32)
614/614 - 0s - loss: 0.6915 - accuracy: 0.6531 - val_loss: 0.6897 - val_accuracy: 0.6429
Epoch 2/10
First layer output of epoch: 2 Tensor("dense_42/Relu:0", shape=(None, 3), dtype=float32)
614/614 - 0s - loss: 0.6874 - accuracy: 0.6531 - val_loss: 0.6853 - val_accuracy: 0.6429
Epoch 3/10
First layer output of epoch: 3 Tensor("dense_42/Relu:0", shape=(None, 3), dtype=float32)
614/614 - 0s - loss: 0.6824 - accuracy: 0.6531 - val_loss: 0.6783 - val_accuracy: 0.6429
```